# problem with flash RectDraw size

Tags: flash

I am testing flash online here
http://wonderfl.net/c/sqop

I'm newbie.

The picture I want to show http://reboltutorial.com/files/2010/05/rebodex-yuml-300x262.png is 300x262

so my rectangle is of the same size. Why does Flash truncate my picture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you add a mask that starts at `(100,100)`, but your loader is located at `(0,0)` move it  to `(100,100)`.

But since your mask is the same size of your loaded image you don't need it.

here a fork with the loader moved :  http://wonderfl.net/c/v6J5

Comment: Ah yes that's better thanks. I don't know what a mask really is: I had just copied and paste some code from adobe :)